# Convex hull of union over extreme points of hypercuboids is equivalent to convex hull of extreme point of a union over hypercuboids?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Assume that $X,Y,Z$ are three hypercuboid with the same dimension $k$. Specifically, we have $X=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_k:0\leq x_i\leq c_i, \forall\,i\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,y_2,...,y_k:0\leq y_i\leq b_i, \forall\,i\}$ and $Z=\{z_1,z_2,...,z_k:0\leq z_i\leq a_i, \forall\,i\}$ where each $c_i$ and $b_i$ and $a_i$ are constant positive real number. My question is whether the following equality holds or not:
$$\text{Conv}(\text{extr}(X\cup Y\cup Z))=\text{Conv}(\text{extr}(X)\cup\text{extr}(Y)\cup\text{extr}(Z))$$
where $\text{Conv}$ means convex hull and $\text{extr}(X)$ means the extreme points of the set $X$.

I conjecture that the equality is also true by drawing a toy example with $k=2$. However, I cannot argue it mathematically. Is there any hint or steps? Thank you!

**Edit**: The definition of the extreme point is that a point in a compact set $A$ is an extreme point if this point cannot be any linear combination of any other two distinct points in $A$.

Comment: In this definition of hypercubes. All of them  are $X \subseteq Y \subseteq Z $ or their permutation becaulse of linearity of  "<" order. In this case this is true. If include translations of them include case of rotations. It changes a lot

Comment: @AdamWrzesiński Yes, there is no rotation. But why $X\subset Y\subset Z$ is correct? For example, if $X=\{x_1,x_2:0\leq x_1\leq1, 0\leq x_2\leq 4\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,y_2:0\leq y_1\leq3, 0\leq y_2\leq 1\}$, it would not be $X\subset Y$ or $Y\subset Z$.

Comment: So do you mean more hypercuboid

Comment: Yes, sorry for the misunderstanding. The constant $c_i,a_i,b_i$ are any positive real numbers. I have edited.

Comment: @AdamWrzesiński Could you give me some hints to prove this equality mathematically? Thank you!

Comment: Very important to clarify is how do you define extreme pointts set.

Comment: @AdamWrzesiński Thank you for your reply. I have added the definition of extreme point.

Comment: In this definition it seems to be that for cuboid extr(C) is set of its vertices

Comment: I can answer myself. For the direction of $LHS\subseteq RHS$, it is obvious since $\text{extr}(X\cup Y\cup Z)\subseteq\text{extr}(X)\cup\text{extr}(Y)\text{extr}(Z)$. For the direction of $LHS\supseteq RHS$, it is also evident that the for any $x\in RHS$, $x$ can be represented as the convex combination of three points $y\in\text{extr}(X),z\in\text{extr}(Y),p\in\text{extr}(Z)$. Therefore, since $y\in X\subseteq LHS$ and so does $z,p$ and $LHS$ is a convex set, we have $x\in LHS$, thereby completing the proof. Does it make sense?

Comment: In the beginning you've seem mistaken sides as bigger set has bigger range of choices so has more extreme points

Comment: @AdamWrzesiński In my opinion, the union would not create new extreme points but may eliminate some extreme points (some extreme points of $X$ may be a convex combination of two points in $Y$ and $Z$ respectively). So bigger range does not mean more extreme points.

Comment: For any $x\in\text{extr}(X\cup Y\cup Z)$, $x$ may be in $X$ or $Y$ or $Z$ and it cannot be any convex combination of any two distinct points in $X$ or $Y$ or $Z$. So, $x\in\text{extr}(X)\cup\text{extr}(Y)\cup\text{extr}(Z)$.